# Using MongoDb Aggregation Pipeline to query top 10 items based on specific type

Tags: mongodb, sorting, collections, aggregation

I have a MongoDb collection that contains document of type

```
{
Type = "."
Person_name = "...."
Income = ...
}
```

Let say Type can contain only 3 type of values A,B,C and person name denotes different persons and Income denotes there respective income.

I want to find the top 10 person in each type having the heighest income.
Then how can I write a MongoDb Aggregation query to that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use $facet https://mongoplayground.net/p/GwmPsn4beZz

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "personA": [
        {
          "$match": {
            Type: "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            Income: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 10
        }
      ],
      "personB": [
        {
          "$match": {
            Type: "B"
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            Income: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 10
        }
      ],
      "personC": [
        {
          "$match": {
            Type: "C"
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            Income: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Pipeline stage in facet:

- match: it matches person type
- sort: it sorts based on income
- limit: it ensures top 10 records

Comment: What if Type take more than 3 different Values then?

Comment: Like more than 30-40 values

Comment: in that case use this https://mongoplayground.net/p/-MTbcYVkziQ pls note you should not run this on very very large data set as nested array sorting would be expensive. but in general this solution works.